# Schengen Visa Main Country

Tags: schengen-visas, applications

I will be arriving in Sweden for 2 days, followed by 2 days in Denmark and finally 5 days in Germany.

With that itinerary, I should apply Schengen at German Embassy, however, there are no time slots available for my appointment before I leave.

What should I do? Apply to the Sweden Embassy instead?

Comment: The plan you've described will not work if you can't get a visa from the German consulate. Be in better time next time.

Comment: You might try to argue that Sweden or Denmark is your main destination if there is a specific thing you want to do there, and the days in Germany are simply tacked on as an afterthought. But if that is not convincing, they will tell you to go to a German consulate and you have lost even more time.

Answer (score 1):

Generally one applies for a visa for the country in which they'll spend the most time, in your particular case that is Germany.

One applies for a visa for the country which is the port of entry only when the stay in multiple countries is the same in duration.

ie:

2 days Sweden (Port of Entry)
2 days Germany
2 days Denmark

[Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=LEGISSUM%3Ajl0028):

> The EU country that is the sole or the main destination of the visit is responsible for examining the visa application. If the main destination cannot be determined, the country of entry into the EU is competent.

I suggest you call or email the Embassy, as sometimes their online systems do not update to show cancelled appointments which are available. (From my experience with the Austrian consulate).

Comment: Thanks, it is a shame I cannot go to Germany. What are my options if there are still no more avails. Should I edit my itinerary and spend most days in Sweden?

Comment: @Yesi Editing your itinerary would work, either increase your days in Sweden to the same as in Germany (then you can apply with Sweden as that's your port of entry) or decrease your days in Germany to be the same as in Sweden.